# How to split string with different characters in postgresql

Tags: string, postgresql

I am looking for a way to split a string into several sub-strings using Postgresql, but the sub-strings are separated by different characters.

For example, the string is like

`"Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday"`

The expected result is like

```
"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"
```

I have found regexp_split_to_array and string_to_array, but it seems to only handle one character as the delimiter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`regexp_split_to_array` (and `regex_split_to_table`) certainly doe handle different delimiters.

```
regress=> SELECT regexp_split_to_table('"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"', '[, ]');
 regexp_split_to_table 
-----------------------
 "Monday"
 "Tuesday"
 "Wednesday"
 "Thursday"
 "Friday"
 "Saturday"
 "Sunday"
(7 rows)
```

Use `regexp_split_to_array` if you prefer an array, and `array_to_string` if you want to turn the array back into a delimited string, e.g.

```
regress=> SELECT array_to_string(regexp_split_to_array('"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"', '[, ]'), ',');
                            array_to_string                             
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 "Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"
(1 row)
```

Please go read https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55871/postgresql-list-of-integers-separated-by-comma-or-integer-array-for-performance ; if you're storing this data in the DB it's probably a design issue you should look at.

Answer (score 2):

Try this Query

```
SELECT string_agg(value, ',') FROM 
(
SELECT regexp_split_to_table('"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"', '[, ]')AS Value
) A
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/2233)**

Output:

---

```
"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"
```

Comment: Why would you do that when you can use `regexp_split_to_array` and `array_to_string`?